# Select Data between current time - 15 mins and current time in SQL

Tags: sql, timestamp

I am looking to pull data between two time periods at only 15 to 30 mins apart. I want to be able to rerun the code multiple times to constantly update the data I had already pulled. I know there is a function for current system time but I am unable to use it effectively in SQL developer.

I have tried using the function CURRENT_TIMESTAMP but could not get it to work effectively.

Currently i am using the following code and just pulling over a broad time frame,  but i would like to shrink that down to 15 to 30 minute intervals that could be used to continue to pull updated data.

I expect to be able to pull current data within 15 to 30 minute segments of time.

Comment: What database engine are you using? MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server, etc.? They're all different when it comes to manipulating dates and times.

Comment: I am using SQL developer.

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer?  Also you might want to add your code.